# Laravel route resource issue

Tags: php, laravel

I use:

- wampserver
- laravel 5
- bootstrap v3.3.6

I'm new in laravel, I usually use a manual `route::get`. Now I try to use `route:resource` to make things faster but somehow those two display different result even though it's should be showing the same page.

My `routes` code:

```
Route::get('create', 'PostController@create');
Route::resource('posts','PostController');
```

[image: SS]
as you can see above, it's directing to the same controller

`PostController@create` code:

```
public function create()
{
    $data['title'] = ' | Create Post';
    return view('posts.create',$data);
}
```

When I go to `blog.dev/create` (which is from `route::get`). It's successfully displaying:
[image: SS 2]

BUT, when I go to `blog.dev/posts/create` (which is from `route::resource`). It's showing a css-less page:
[image: SS 3]

Why is that happen? any way to fix it? (I prefer not to use `route::get`)

Note:

- I've tried different browsers, clear cookies&cache and restarting wamp
- Both have exactly the same code in `view page source` from browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be issue with css file paths. Your css paths are relative.

make your css file path to be absolute.

Read this:-

https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url

http://jeffreybarke.net/2013/06/paths-and-urls-relative-and-absolute/